# sed not working properly inside find's "exec"

Tags: unix, sed, replace, find, exec

I am working on a one-liner to remove the extensions to a bulk of files in a location.

This is what it looks like, and it should work, but it does not:

```
find . -type f -name '*.txt' -exec mv {} $( echo {} | sed 's/\.txt//g'  )  \;
```

The replacement never took place. "mv" is stating:

```
mv: \`./partaa.txt' and `./partaa.txt' are the same file
```

I know the problem is within here:

```
$( echo {} | sed 's/\.txt//g'  )
```

But if I try something like this, it works perfectly:

```
echo $( echo "partaa.txt" | sed 's/.txt//g' )
```

Why is it not working when it is part of "exec"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do is not supported.  In the `man` page for `find` in the `PRIMARIES` section under `-exec`, it states:

*Utility and arguments are not subject to the further expansion of shell patterns and constructs.*

However, you can use `find` to generate fodder for a `sed` command that creates a command stream that you can pipe into `bash`.  Then you can troubleshoot by removing the `bash` from the pipeline:

```
find . -type f -name '*.txt' | sed 's/.*/mv & &/; s/\.txt$//' | bash -x
```

The first `sed` `s` command creates a `mv` string with both filenames the same, the second `s` command removes the `.txt` from the second one.

The '-x' tells bash to display each command as it executes. You can safely omit it.

Comment: Thanks so much @Greg Tarsa. :) This works like charm. regarding to my above question, so my problem was quoting right? Do you know exactly what I was quoting wrongly ?

Comment: I have to confess I do not.  I recall spending an hour or two some years ago trying to get `-exec` to do something similar, finally hit on creating a set of bash commands and never looked back.  However, in re-reading the `find` man page, I found a restriction that may prevent that solution at all.  I have updated my answer to include it.

Comment: If this answer is correct, please mark it so.  Thanks!

Comment: I have done so. Thanks so much for all your help buddy. :)

Comment: My pleasure, I am happy to help.